# Attach MDF File To SSMS

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to attach a .mdf file to my SSMS install.  I go through the steps and at the very end I get this message.

What is causing the .mdf file to not attach?

Also, I have verified that the .mdf file is **NOT** read only.

[image]

**EDIT**
If I run `Select @@Version` I get the output that I have 2008 which is what my .mdf file requires..

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message clearly states, the version of the `*.mdf` file you are trying to attach is the internal version 661.

> The database 'E:\PRAKASH_PRIVATE\ACADEMIC DOC\PROJECT_DOC\MYPROJECT R3\MYPROJECT\APP_DATA\SHOPING.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 661.

The SQL Server you are running supports the internal version number 655 and earlier.

> This server support version 655 and earlier. A downgrade is not supported.

To attach the MDF file you would have to find the corresponding SQL Server version number that has the internal database version 661 (the MDF file). This turns out to be SQL Server version 2008 R2.

The SQL Server version you are running is less than SQL Server 2008 R2 (possibly 2008).

***Reference:** [Microsoft SQL Server Internal Database Versions and Compatibility Levels](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2014/01/sql-server-internal-database-versions.html)*

The table is reproduced here to provide a complete source:

```
SQL Server Version  | Internal Database Version | Database Compatibility Level
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 2019 CTP | 895 / 904                 | 150
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 2017     | 869                       | 140
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 2016     | 852                       | 130
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 2014     | 782                       | 120
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 2012     | 706                       | 110
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 2012 CTP1|                           |
(a.k.a. 2011 Denali)| 684                       | 110
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 2008 R2  | 660 / 661                 | 100
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 2008     | 655                       | 100
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 2005 SP2+|                           | 
VarDecimal enabled  | 612                       | 90
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 2005     | 611                       | 90
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 2000     | 539                       | 80
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 7.0      | 515                       | 70
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------ 
SQL Server 6.5      | 408                       | 65    
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
SQL Server 6.0      | ?                         | 60
--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------
```

Your assumption that....

> If I run Select @@Version I get the output that I have 2008 which is what my .mdf file requires..

...is wrong. The mdf file contains a database with the version **SQL Server 2008 R2** which is not the same as your SQL Server version **SQL Server 2008**.

To attache the mdf file you would have to install **SQL Server 2008 R2**.

Comment: It looks like I do have two instances installed.  How do I find the name to connect to?  For example, services.msc shows
SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) AND
SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)

I connect to the express version like
DESKTOP-UR15MF7\SQLEXPRESS
If I try DESKTOP-UR15MF7\MSSQLSERVER it errors.

Comment: OMG - I feel stupid.  It's just localhost, lol.  Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates (and there is no way) to downgrade `.MDF`, the only way is to [script out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/scripting-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) from higher version and use that generated script in lower version SQL Server.

Comment: I thought it was for SQL 2008 R2 - and that is what I am trying to attach to.... Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)   Mar 29 2009 10:11:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: @user2676140, Hope, [Hot2use](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/15356/hot2use) made it clear!